# Show unit circle under multiplication not isomorphic to either the nonzero real numbers under multiplication or real numbers under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, problem-solving, group-isomorphism

I am trying to answer Fraleigh's Abstract Algebra textbook question from Exercises 4 (pg 45) q. 9.

"Show that the group $(U,\cdot)$ is NOT isomorphic to either $(\mathbb R^*,\cdot)$ or $(\mathbb R,+)$. All three groups have cardinality $|\mathbb R|$."

Here, $U$ is the group $\{z \in \mathbb C \mid  |z| = 1\}$.

I have no idea of the answer. I cant find any properties that are unique. I can show that the second two groups arent isomorphic but I have no idea how to begin.

I'd like if someone can give me a hint on how to approach. Thanks!

Comment: try to find an element $x$ and an integer $n$ such that $x^n = 1$ in each of the groups.(of course such that $x\neq 1$)

Comment: Have a look at how I edited your question so that you learn some LaTeX on the way.

Comment: @Thomas, you could post that hint as a hint-answer :-)

Comment: Thank you, I know LaTeX i didnt know you could put it on here. Ill have to look into how on here. Here you use 1 as the identity correct? And the exponential notation is just repeated group operation?

Comment: How could I go about thinking of properties to test when testing for isomorphism?

Comment: In $U$ the order of $i,-i,1,-1$ is finite.

Comment: It's not actually LaTeX that you use, but a different flavor of TeX called "mathjax" https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4):

In the group $U$ there  are more than two elements  whose order is finite namely, $i,-i,1,-1$. But in other two groups, it's not true. As in $(\mathbb{R}^*,\times)$ only $\pm1$ are of finite order and in $(\mathbb{R},+)$ there is no element of finite order.

Comment: There are more elements of finite order, like $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(1+I)$, but you have enough.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't been exposed to concepts like order yet. Only the concept of a group being a set with a binary operation, associativity of the binary operation, an identity, and the existence of inverses for every element.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't got order concepts of an element right now, I am giving my answer in elaborating concept of order concept.

Two groups are isomorphic if they share every group theoretic property. That is they are *only notationally different*.

Now note that the group $(U,.)$ has four elements $1, -1, i, -i$ having the property $x^4=1$. So if $(\mathbb R^*,.)$ is isomorphic to $(U,.)$ it should contain distinct four element with similar property. But $(\mathbb R^*,.)$ have only two elements namely $1$ and $-1$ such that $x^4=1.$

Also if we consider the the group $(\mathbb R,+)$ then it only have one element $0$ satisfying the property $4x=0$(as operation is $+,$ equation is written in addition format). So they are not isomorphic as we *can't* say groups are *only notationally different* as they are different in property also.

Answer (score 0):

The group $U$ contains elements $x,y$ such that $x^3=y^3$ but $x\ne y.$ Neither of the other two groups has the corresponding property.